# link database to sql source control is very slow

Tags: ssms

When i try to link my data base to sql source control it is taking nearly about an hour and when i try to click cancel,  the process is again slow.
This is making my work slow down.
Please some one help me.
I am using SQL server 2012 database and connecting to the latest version of Red gate source control 3.8.11.103.

Comment: What do you mean? Are you trying to commit the entire database and all its contents to source control? Or just the database structure and definitions of objects? If the former, that's a very bad idea, and you're lucky it's so fast.

Comment: i am not commiting..I am at the first step to link my database to the TFS source control.since the database is not getting linked i am not able to get the latest.